# What option should replace the question mark?

Tags: pattern

[image]

I am quite stuck on how to figure this out, everyone in the comments says it's 14, not sure how they ended up on that answer.

Sourced: https://www.facebook.com/kailashdhakalKD/photos/a.111319136881205/598793478133766/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fairly sure the answer is:

> The first digit is the number of empty squares above that cell, until it reaches the edge of the table, or another cell with a number in it.
>
>  The second digit is the number of empty squares below that cell.
>
>  So in the far right, there will be 1 empty square above, and 4 empty squares below, and the answer is 14.
>
>  [image]

Comment: Yeah, one of the comments on the source translates to rot13("Sebag rzcgl obk = 1 / Onpx rzcgl obk = 4"), which alas I was still unable to catch on to the pattern.